# Boosting specific field value in Elastic search

Tags: search, elasticsearch

Hi I need to boost the documents based on the on a particular value of a field.. My documents contains a field called Region.. Based on the value present in the region i need to boost my documents..
These are my documents

```
{
    "title":"INOX: Malleshwaram - Mantri Square",
    "region":"Bangalore"
  }

    {
    "title":"INOX: Bund Garden Road",
    "region":"Pune"
   }

   {
    "title":"INOX: Glomax Mall, Kharghar",
    "region":"Mumbai"
  }
```

I have tried to use rescore query in my query which look like this

```
"rescore" : {
      "query" : {
          "score_mode":"total",
          "query_weight" : 2.5,
         "rescore_query_weight" : 0.5,
         "rescore_query" : {
            "match" : {
               "region" : {
                  "query" : "mumbai",
                   "slop" : 2
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But its not working properly as required..Is there any way to solve this?..
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why** rescoring, all you need is boosting. Based on the query type you are using, boosting is possible in

```
"query_string": {
  "fields":["region^56"],
  "use_dis_max" : true,
      "query": "mumbai"
}
```

where ^56 is the boosting value.

You can also use as mentioned here http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-boosting-query.html

If you are using the bool query you can use boost like this to boost all queries

```
{
"bool" : {
    "must" : {
        "term" : { "region" : "mumbai" }
    },
    "boost" : 25.0
}
```

}

Comment: I am sorry i didnot clearly explained the problem..I have documents with events also..I need to give priority to events then venue with that region..example

Comment: {
    "title":"Inorder",
    "type":"movie"
  } if this is my event then it should display event first then the venue of that place..

Comment: Is ther a other way to boost occurences in specific fields? I do not want to put all my fields into "fields":[field1, field2...]. I want to search all fields but boost only some. THX

Comment: some day i needed to boost records that have a specific field not empty like profile picture first.   
i done so by adding a should to the bool query and it will add points to every occurrence in the should    
so if you need all people that named "shady" and please give me the people who have a profile picture    
this is easy by query name in a must query and picture in should with minimum should match 0      
`"bool" : {
    "must" : {
        "term" : { "name" : "shady" }
    },
 "should" : {
        "term" : { "have_pp" : "yes" }
    }
}`